# Загрузка данных из БД, конвертация их в массив объектов и операции с ними в JS

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, база-данных

Я вывожу из БД все данные которые подходят под условие.

```
<?php
include ('../connection/db.php');
$time = date('U');

$query = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM `mess1` WHERE(`time` - '$time' <= 3600000)");

$result = $query or die(mysqli_error());
while($count = mysqli_fetch_all($result))
{
    echo json_encode($count);
}

mysqli_close($connection);
?>
```

Вот вопрос :`mysqli_fetch_all($result)` возвращает ассоциативный массив, но мне нужно что бы в те данные которые вернул запрос принимались в другой функции в таком же виде, в котором их возвращает например `$.getJSON`(см. фото), скажите как это осуществить?

```
function data() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "data.php",
        success: function(someData){
            callback(someData);
        },
        error: function() {
            alert('Error');
        }
    });
}
data();

function callback(respond) {
    //some operations with data
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
function data() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "php/data.php",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(someData) {
      callback(someData);
    },
    error: function() {
      alert('Eror!');
    }
  });
}
var exists = [];
data();

function callback(respond) {
  var timeNow = Date.now();
  for (var i = 0; i < respond.length; i++) {
    var data = respond[i];

    if (exists.indexOf(data.id) != -1) continue;

    var timeInMessage = data.time * 1000;
    var diff_time = (timeNow - timeInMessage);

    if (diff_time <= 3600000) {
      var rowClone = $('.mess_hide').clone().removeClass('mess_hide');

      var newDate = new Date(timeInMessage);
      var dateArray = [newDate.getHours(), newDate.getMinutes(), newDate.getSeconds()]
      var res = dateArray.map(function(x) {
        return x < 10 ? "0" + x : x;
      }).join(":");

      $('#messages').append(rowClone);
      $('.time', rowClone).html(res);
      $('.name', rowClone).html(data.user);
      $('.message', rowClone).html(smile(data.message));
      $('.scroller').scrollTop($('#messages').height());

      exists.push(data.id);
    }
  }
  setTimeout(function() {
    data();
  }, 1000);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: А почему должно быть 25 записей? В запросе к БД я не увидел ограничение на число выводимых записей.

Comment: В запросе сказано вывести все записи, а конкретно на данный момент их 25.

Comment: Вы там в phpmyadmin выберите количество отображаемых строк на странице не 25, а 500 и удивитесь наличию новых записей в таблице mess1 ;)

Comment: @Visman моя вина) а скажите пожалуйста что-то по поводу этого вопроса: И ещё вопрос, mysqli_fetch_all($result) возвращает ассоциативный массив, но мне нужен массив объектов, скажите как это осуществить? Как видно я пробовал json_encode но вышло что-то не то..)

Comment: не совсем понял, зачем вам php-массив, но предположим, что очень надо :)   mysqli_fetch_all возвращает массив ассоциативных массивов. Одномерный массив (т.е. один из этих массивов) можно превратить в объект простым кастом - `$row_obj = (object)$row_array;`. С многомерным уже так не выйдет, надо писать свой преобразователь (опять же, если надо весь набор результатов из БД превратить в один объект - то несложно, один foreach и аналогичный каст одномерных массивов внутри цикла). Если размерность неизвестна - ну надо значит рекурсивно делать, но врядли в данном случае речь об этом.

Comment: ну т.е., другими словами, если вам именно объект нужен, чтобы json_encode выдавал именно как объекты - то `echo json_encode((object)$count);`

Comment: @AlexandrX смотрите, мне нужно что бы в `js` функцию данные заходили в таком виде:` [{…}, {…}]
0
:
{time: "1505829140", user: "max", message: "Hello", id: 1}
1
:
{time: "1505829144", user: "max", message: "Hello", id: 2}
length
:
2
__proto__
:
Array(0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы оперируете json'ом и его отправляете обратно в коллбек аякса, но принимаете в нём не json. Добавьте в js формат принимаемых данных:

```
dataType: "json",
```

.. и должно сразу заработать.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

> dataType .. "json": Evaluates the response as JSON and returns a JavaScript object.

Comment: `AJAX` выбил `alert('Error');`. В консоли написало `Uncaught TypeError: data is not a function`. Прикрепил к вопросу фото.

Comment: что за ошибка, можно узнать на вкладке отладчика Сеть. глянуть что там реально прилетело с бэкэнда. а почему дата не есть функция я хз, она у вас объявлена строкой выше вызова. приведите пример кода целиком как есть. явно что-то не так цитируете.

Comment: Добавил в вопрос.

Comment: ну вот! и сразу видно, как функцию data затирает вот это присвоение `var data = respond[i];`. вы её прибили, вот её и нет.

Comment: Спасибо, ошибок нет, но почему-то сама функция не делает то, что нужно, то есть не выводит на экран данные. Не знаете с чем это может быть связано?

Answer (score 0):

> @AlexandrX смотрите, мне нужно что бы в js функцию данные заходили в
>   таком виде: `[{…}, {…}] 0 : {time: "1505829140", user: "max", message:
>   "Hello", id: 1} 1 : {time: "1505829144", user: "max", message:
>   "Hello", id: 2} length : 2 proto : Array(0)`

а, ну тогда вам надо сначала сформировать *массив объектов*, а потом уже json-энкодить его.

```
// ...
$output = [];  
while($count = mysqli_fetch_all($result)) 
   $output[] = (object)$count; 
echo json_encode($output);
// ...
```